# Java: How are classes like the "System" class are implemented so that they are readily available and accessible everywhere?

Tags: java, object

I come from a C background, so not so familiar with the Java naming conventions, and still new to Java, so I am sorry if this question is overly simple.
I would like to implement a class/object that is readily available by simply importing its header?

Thanx!

Comment: [`class System`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/lang/System.java?av=f).

Comment: There are no header files in Java, a class is defined and implemented in one file.

Answer (score 4):

`System` is a part of `java.lang` and All classes in the `java.lang` package are imported by default.

from [specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html)

> A compilation unit automatically has access to all types declared in
>   its package and also automatically imports all of the public types
>   declared in the predefined package java.lang

EDIT:

So to answer your question, classes like `System` are implemented the same way we implement classes in Java, it is just that those are default imported to be readily available.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will learn more about what you kindly referenced, and then I will followup on this post.